# Are there any contests for teenage writers?

Tags: novel

Are there writing competitions/awards for novel length works by authors under 18?

There are certainly [prizes for professional novelists](http://www.themanbookerprize.com/), and [amateur novelists](http://www.yeovilprize.co.uk/), but I'm looking for something for under 18s or under 16s...

Comment: a publishing contract?

Comment: Any type of compeition - be it cash, a nice certificate, or just something to be proud of winning :)

Comment: :) No, sorry, I was being snarky. "A winning competition for a novel" *is* getting a publishing contract.

Comment: Yes, please. I asked a similar question a while back, what do you think the answers were? I hope you have better luck.

Comment: Can you narrow down what you're looking for? As the question is written right now, it'll essentially generate a list to which there can be no clear best answer.

Comment: I'd be happy with a simple yes/no answer (with an example if yes)  @LaurenIpsum - :) If you can find a publisher that takes only under 18's then I'd gladly accept...

Comment: Why does the publisher have to accept *only* under X age?

Comment: I'd guess it's because the contest wants to promote the art of writing to individuals. I won a contest 2 years back that was college-students only, but that was a poetry contest. I dont have examples for a novel writing contest, but I'm sure there's bound to be some. The catch is they tend to be really obscure around the internet. Try asking your school for help

Comment: [Yes, there are.](http://www.amazon.com/Editors-Picks-Kindle-eBooks/b/ref=bhp_banner_kids_A?ie=UTF8&node=353898011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-1&pf_rd_r=A29C3B68AD9B4995A95D&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1500726222&pf_rd_i=390919011)

Comment: Hi John, but confused by the link - it seams to be amazon's editors picks; I can't find anything mentioning under-18s or under-16s anywhere :(

Comment: It depends where are you. Normally, university-based organizations have annual writing contests.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes there are awards though not as highly recognized as the major awards which are open to everyone. Also these awards are fairly localised. Normally your country has its own junior writing awards. You'll have to search on your government's site find out more about that. The relatively major awards for young authors are generally only for published books and if you win one of them you stand a chance doing having success in the normal competitions. Generally though they don't differentiate writers by age groups.